# How can I return a data type other than function type in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm trying to build a Tree for practicing searching algorithms and I need to access a null pointer in order to make sure a particular node is empty upon creation... However, I can't figure out how to get a null pointer to return from a T& type function. Right now I have the nullptr defined as a standard

```
int * key = 0;
```

The function that needs to access and return a nullptr is

```
T& getData() { ... }
```

I looked into implicit conversion, but I am not sure if that's the right way to go, or even how to do it. Also, it might be useful to know that I have to build everything in a single header file and the main file can't be changed. Thanks in advance for any insight that can help me to understand how to approach this!

Comment: References cannot be null, that is the point of them!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: Thank you marsh. I should add there there is a function that checks if getData() returns a nullptr in the main file... Is there any possible way to return a nullptr from a T&?

Comment: It is technically possible but would be very bad coding. You should return T* instead if you want it to be null. Or you could return a reference to the type and make the type a class with a pointer inside that can be null or not then have a IsValid() method. I am not sure you understand pointers and references correctly. It might be worth reading up on them a bit.

Comment: As marsh mentioned, references cannot be null. You can have a pointer to null but references are not pointers.

Comment: Unless you mean you want a reference to a pointer?

Comment: You could also use a `boost::optional` if pointers don't suit you.

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns a `T&` must return a reference to a `T`, and references cannot be NULL. As such, you cannot return NULL - you would effectively have to `return *NULL;`, which for obvious reasons is invalid.

You have a few options:

1. Convert the `T&` to a `T*`. You may then return `NULL` or `nullptr`. I would suggest avoiding 0 as a symbol for a NULL, as it is potentially confusing.
2. Throw an exception. If `getData()` is *supposed* to return a reference to data, it might be fair to assume getting data that does not exist (to provide a reference for) is undefined behavior/a bug and can be treated as such.
3. Depending on what `T` actually is (is this really a template, or is `T` just shorthand?), you could create a "NullType" for that type. For example, you might have a `Data` isa `DataInterface`, and `NullData` isa `DataInterface`.
4. In some *very* rare cases, returning a reference to some sort of "dead" data (think `/dev/null`) is an option. I doubt it is in this case, as you likely want to *know* that the value returned was invalid; however, in cases where data *absolutely must* be returned and you have no data, creating a static object to return in these cases can be a trick to pair with error reporting.

I would say the only particularly good option you have is the one you have ruled out, #1.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response... the T mentioned is a custom type defined in the main class, it is called SizeHolder.  The creation in the class is

Comment: TreeNode<SizeHolder>* size_root = new TreeNode<SizeHolder>(create(5));

Comment: What it actually has to be is EQUIVALENT to nullptr, but it doesn't necessarily have to be a nullptr... but getData() must return something equivalent to nullptr. Basically what's happening is, I think, a reference of Node<SizeHolder>* must be passed through this getData() function and return an equivalence of nullptr...

Answer (score 0):

> However, I can't figure out how to get a null pointer to return from a T& type function.

You cant. If the function is delcared to return a reference to a `T`, it has to return a reference to a `T` not a pointer.

(...unless `T` is a pointer type, e.g.  `int*` but the you still have to return a reference to a `int*`.)

If you want to have the option to return "nothing" from the function, then make it return a pointer, because references (in contrast to pointers) always reference something.

PS: I hope you are not doing something similar to this:

```
T& getData() {
    T data = T(....);
    return data;   // BOOM // dont do this
}
```